# WPF toolkit Is it possible to scale Chart like Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, charts, scale

I am developing a plot/chart/graph. I want o scale the Y axis on Log of base 10 - so I want values 0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 on Y axis. I am able to get the scale also, but want the values in same distances. Attached snap shots of what I get and what I want :

Results of what I get from my code :
[image: This is what I GET]

[image: Results I am looking for :]  This is a plot generated from Excel. In my app, I want this results i.e. equal distance between numbers.

Code that I use to scale my Y axis :

```
public class LogConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double x = double.Parse(value.ToString());
        int y = (int)x;
        switch (y)
        {
            case 0:
            case 10:
            case 100:
            case 1000:
            case 10000:
            case 100000: 
            case 1000000:
            case 10000000:
                Console.WriteLine("Log = " + value);
                return y.ToString();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I set Min =0 & Max (dynamic) of Y Axis and its interval is set to 10.
Any idea how do I achieve this goal ? Is it possible in WPF ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used OxyPlot open source to achieve my goal

Answer (score 2):

You may have to create your own *logarithmic axis*. This blog has an example: [WPF & Silverlight Charting: A Logarithmic Axis](http://www.cplotts.com/2009/10/09/wpf-silverlight-charting-a-logarithmic-axis/).

Answer (score 0):

Like Tvd said, you can use OxyPlot.

If you look here: [OxyPlot Documentation](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Axes&referringTitle=Feature%20overview) it says the documentation is under construction.
Never the less, head into your code, and you can do this:

```
var logarithmicAxis = new LogarithmicAxis();
```

There are 3 constructors you can use ... it should be smooth sailing from there.